# Yii2 get all cached items by TagDependecy

Tags: php, caching, yii2, tags

Is there a way to get all Yii2 cache values by TagDependency? For invalidating, there is `TagDependency::invalidate()` method, but I can't find any information on getting all values neither in `TagDependency` nor in `Cache` classes. The deal is, I need to load several cached items based on User ID, and their count may vary.

If this is not possible, and there are no other good practices, implementing own Dependency class could be an option, but I don't know where to start. I am using Redis cache if that matters.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the role of dependencies in caching. Their role is to say whether the cached data are still valid or if the data has been changed and must be loaded again. Their role isn't to somehow group the different cache keys together.

Comment: @MichalHynčica thank's for explanation